# How to inject extra property sources in SPRING before other beans are created?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am writing a library which will be used by spring-boot projects. I'd like to inject into the boot projects' `SpringEnvironment` a property source that I take from the Internet.

I tried the following

```
@Configuration
public class MyCustomConfiguration {

  @Bean
  BeanDefinedAbove above() { /* do some work */ }

  @Bean
  @ConditionalOnBean(BeanDefinedAbove.class)
  SmartInitializingSingleton propertySourceSetting(ConfigurableEnvironment env, BeanDefinedAbove bean) {
    return () -> { 
      PropertySource source = bean.getPropertySourceDownloadedFromTheInternet();
      env.getPropertySources().addFirst(source);
    }
  }
}
```

In my clients' projects when I debug this code what happens is either one of the two:

1. `above()` is called
2. user's `@Service` or `@Controller` are called
3. `propertySourceSetting(...)` is called

OR

1. user's `@Service` or `@Controller` are called
2. `above()` is called
3. `propertySourceSetting(...)` is called

Depending whether or not my client's depend on my `BeanDefinedAbove` bean, which is normal as the `@Service` is depdent on the bean created in `above()`.

I have also added the FQDN of my class to the `EnableAutoConfiguration` in the `META-INF/spring.factories`.

So how to ensure that the logic in `propertySourceSetting(..)` is called before users' `@Service` and `@Controller`

Comment: Maybe check how Spring Cloud Config works (ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator class)? Spring cloud config is fetched at the start, so maybe add similar thing.

Comment: Good idea, I will take a look. Meanwhile solutions are still accepted :)

Comment: You can try this system property -Dspring.config.location=foo.com/bar/properties 

It is supposed to let you specify a properties file from a URL and it will add it as a separate propertysource.
Haven't tried myself but I guess this would be a 5 minute test. Let me know if it works! docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/…

Answer (score 0):

I'll provide you with three options.

**Option 1:** (THIS IS A BAD APPROACH, BUT A QUICK WORKAROUND)

Add @Lazy(false) annotation to both Beans. Spring will eagerly create those two beans, which they will probably be created before the other ones.

Why this is bad?
This does not ensure order. Spring decides the creation order based on dependencies and some other conditions. This is why it will "probably" work :)

**Option 2:** Create a main class to bootstrap Spring Boot Initialization (the old way of starting spring boot).

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(MyApplication.class);
   // ... add property source here before start
   application.run(args)
 }
```

You also need to specify main class in the manifest for Spring Boot like this: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-main-class

In that main-class you would add your propertysource, kinda like this:

```
SomeClassThatRetrievesProperties propRetriever = new SomeClassThatRetrievesProperties ();
Map<String,String> properties = propRetriever.getAllPropertiesAsMap(); 
application.setDefaultProperties(properties);
```

**Option 3**: Create a CustomApplicationContext by extending WebApplicationContext and overriding getSpecificConfigurations() method.

This way you will have full control but we aware that you could break some important stuff.

Comment: 1 is pretty bad I agree. I am skipping it. 2 - i cannot do, since I am writing a library and the client's code is not under my control. 3 - seems like an overkill and it seems to me Spring should have thought about how to deal with cases like mine.

Comment: You can try this system property  -Dspring.config.location=foo.com/bar/properties 

Haven't tried myself but I guess this would be a 5 minute test. Let me know if it works! docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/…